# Is there any way to implement PageFactory and @FindBy annotations (selenium) into playwright in typescript

Tags: playwright, page-factory, findby, playwright-typescript

I looked all across the web to see if someone implemented something like that and couldn't find anything. Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance

I am aiming to implement something close to PageFactory and FindBy annotations for playwright, I tried using BardAI suggestions but those didn't work properly as well

Comment: Can you shows us in code , what have you tried so far? and ask for specific suggestions to problems in  piece of code you tried to implement?

Comment: Thank you but I succeeded to implement it eventually. Btw how do I close the question?

Answer (score 0):

**IWebElement** is Selenium, and **Locator** in Playwright is not the same, so there's no sense in using outdated patterns.

Here are the docs that PW suggests PageObject for Java guys https://playwright.dev/java/docs/pom

Comment: Yeah you're right I implemented it only to make the code look cleaner